# Day Calculation is wrong

Tags: javascript

I'm making a clock, that calculates the number of days based on the date that the user input.
Let's say the user input `November 20, 2020`.
However, the calculate was really off, especially, if I put today date (Jan 06, 2021), then calculate started with -6.

Please take a look and let me know where I went wrong with the calculation.
This is my javascript for it:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // console.log("js running");
    var days = document.querySelector('.days span');
    var hour = document.querySelector('.hour');
    var min = document.querySelector('.min');
    var second = document.querySelector('.second');
    
    var startDate = new Date(2020, 11, 20);
    days.innerText = Math.floor((new Date - startDate)/86400000);
    countTime();
    
    function countTime() {
        let today = new Date();
        let ms = (today - startDate) % 86400000;
        hour.innerText = Math.floor(ms / 3600000);
        min.innerText = Math.floor(ms % 3600000 / 60000);
        second.innerText = Math.floor(ms % 3600000 % 60000 / 1000);
    }
    
    setInterval(countTime, 1000);
    
}, false);
```

Comment: *that calcuate number of days based on the date that the user input.* - number of days of what? Please explain..

Comment: The question isn't complete however i recommend using this for difference of days: `var diffDays=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(Math.abs(startDate.getTime()-(new Date).getTime()))`

Comment: @TalRofe Sorry for not being clear enough. But the code that I put in the example is simplier version of my js. But there is a function that ask user to enter their input of their date, which will be input as month, day, and year. So let say, user enter Month is 6 (june), Date is 23, and Year is 2012. Then the code in the example will change, and not  var startDate = new Date(2020, 11, 20); It will be based on the user input.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `ms` variable was the number of days, and you used it in every other calculation, instead of the actual time difference. You can convert the difference to seconds, and work from there:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const $      = document.querySelector.bind(document),
          days   = $('.days span'),
          hour   = $('.hour'),
          min    = $('.min'),
          second = $('.second');
    
    const startDate = new Date(2020, 11, 20);
    countTime();
    
    function countTime() {
        const today     = new Date(),
          diffInSeconds = Math.floor((today - startDate) / 1000);
          
        days.innerText   = Math.floor(diffInSeconds / 86400);
        hour.innerText   = Math.floor(diffInSeconds % 86400 / 3600);
        min.innerText    = Math.floor(diffInSeconds %  3600 / 60);
        second.innerText = Math.floor(diffInSeconds %    60);
    }
    
    setInterval(countTime, 1000);
});
```

```html
<span class="days"><span></span></span> days
<span class="hour"></span> hours
<span class="min"></span> minutes
<span class="second"></span> seconds
```